# Telerik Report : Starch line in Detail band or Add Empty rows

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I am trying generate one sale bill format format in telerik report design.

I Need Output like detail band is grow to fit page size. like adding blank row.
i have used table inside details band.

Is there any property in detail band or in table to fit page size?
 or i have to manually add blank rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Docking` property by selecting the table and then using the property window to set the value.

Set it to Fill by clicking in the value box and selecting `Fill`.

Alternatively you can just type `Fill`.

Comment: i try your solution. but i want to implement table/detail band like even when there is one record in table but table vertices line should starch up to page footer. like we add blank record to reach page footer. like sample image [link]http://imgur.com/pPffj